# Is there a Wordpress php function that can return just the URL of the Custom Logo image(not the full image tag)?

Tags: php, wordpress, url

I am trying to code a small custom wordpress theme. So I am overriding on the twentytwenty theme of wordpress.

Just to be clear I am talking PHP and overriding home.php, where I want to create some custom html header.

I am trying to **get the url of the logo** (that I (or the user, can change) using the wordpress customizer.

What I did is :

```
<img src="<?php echo (get_custom_logo()) ? get_custom_logo() : 'somefallback_url'; ?>" >
```

What is happening is :

> get_custom_logo() function is returning an Image which is normal, I can't find the function that should return the URL in the codex. An error is happening i have an image inside another one.

So basically what I want is :

> **A PHP function that returns just the URL** not the full Image tag.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [codex](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_custom_logo/) lies it out for you

```
function get_custom_logo_url()
{
    $custom_logo_id = get_theme_mod( 'custom_logo' );
    $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $custom_logo_id , 'full' );
    return $image[0];
}
```

Comment: Man your get_custom_logo_url() is not included by default in the Wordpress PHP Framework. I got huge errors after trying the direct call. I had to declare it by adding the code snippet to my theme functions.php. And then it Worked. Thanks for the Answer.

Comment: Well, yes! Custom code needs to be included in the functions.php or elsewhere in the theme

Comment: Sure, Thanks for the answer I will pay much more attention to these User Contributed Notes.

Answer (score 8):

For a short one-liner:

```
<?php echo esc_url( wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_theme_mod( 'custom_logo' ), 'full' )[0] ); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to return only the image src URL you can use this with the simplest way.

```
$custom_logo_id = get_theme_mod( 'custom_logo' );
$image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_url ( $custom_logo_id , 'full' );
```